# Why are there no standalone PHP applications?

Tags: php, server-side

How come a lot of the popular server-side languages (Java, Python, Perl, etc.) are also very popular for creating standalone programs, but it's not the case for PHP? Is it even possible to write a standalone PHP application? If so, could it have GUI?

Comment: [There are GUI bindings for PHP](http://gtk.php.net/) (even if they aren't maintained much), but PHP's heritage is as a web scripting language, and that's where its strengths lie. It certainly _can_ be used as a general purpose scripting language with a GUI, it just isn't done much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP was designed specifically for web pages unlike Java and Python which were designed for applications in general (PHP in the beginning meant Personal Home Pages), and this is why it isn't used that much outside the web. You can, however, use PHP in the command line and therefore make executable scripts, but there is only one GUI binding that I currently know of: [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/). Development of PHP-GTK appears to have stopped two years ago, but it should be mostly reliable. Also, there appears to be a project that [compiles PHP scripts to executables](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php), even though that, too, is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at why each language was created. 
PHP was created [specifically for web development](http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php). 
As for the other languages, they are all capable of web development, but Perl was created specifically for [text extraction](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~zurawski/perl/2.html), Java was for [mobile devices](http://java.about.com/od/gettingstarted/a/whatisjava.htm), and Python was for [scripting](http://docs.python.org/faq/general.html#why-was-python-created-in-the-first-place).

PHP can be used outside of web development. The best known implementation is [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/). It's just not as common, as you have seen already.